Unique values in SQL by time
There is a table like:
GUID | number | dt_start

How should the request look correctly so that when counting numbers, the time difference between calls is taken into account; if the call was with a difference of more than 1 hour, then consider it to be taken into account?
1 | 1234567890 | 04/08/2024 11:00
2 | 1234567890 | 04/08/2024 12:01
3 | 1234567890 | 04/08/2024 13:00

The result should be 2.
I can't find the right function to solve this problem.

If ... the time difference between calls ... is the difference between the current and the previous row, then a combination of LAG() and DATEDIFF() is an option.

if there are a lot of lines, will the LAG() function solve this problem?

Check this example https://dbfiddle.uk/7pf4yQ40

This question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70848946/i-need-to-get-datediff-on-each-row-based-on-previous-row

@BartMcEndree Slightly modified solution to account for the first row.

Thank you very much, this is what I needed, I have never encountered LAG before
